# KeywordQuery to search by BCS Entity Name and Namespace

Tags: search, bcs

I have built a custom search connector to crawl and index external content types. That works quite well. I find the index entities in the search center as well through using the API of SearchServiceApplicationProxy.

But now I want to know, what is the easiest way to narrow the result of a KeywordQuery to just get results from an certain Entity-Type (e.g just the "Products" of the external system, not the "Customers"). That means I want to query by the Name and Namespace of the Entity (in conjunction with an some other search terms).

Do I have to create a managed property myself based on some crawled property? Or is there a way to fill for example the "ContentType" or "ContentClass" property from the BCS-connector?
Thank you in advance.

### Regards

Joachim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to make a custom property and then create a scope on that property, looking for a specific value.

I have had a play on a similar set up just now and I can't find a way to do it another way.

It's a small workaround but it works.

Comment: I did it exactly that way now. By using a DefaultValue in the .bdcm-Model it is completely declerative. I mapped the new CrawledProperty now to the ManagedProperty "contentclass". This mapping is done via PS-Cmdlet in our setup-script. I'dont think it is required to build a scope. I use just a HiddenConstraint in my KeywordQuery. Thank you very much.

Comment: The scope just creates a copy of the data and puts less stress on the server, that is why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are looking for are already automatically created for you by SharePoint, "EntityName" and "EntityNamespace". You don't even need to create the managed properties and map them. Take a look at Search Service Administration page in the Central Administration and "Metadata properties" section.